# Calling method in F# with named parameters on multiple lines

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have some F# code that calls a method written in C# with lots of parameters.

In order to make things legible I use *named parameters* when calling the method:

```
let request = Models.UserService.CreateUserRequest(
    email = "email@example.com",
    password = "password",
    title = "title",
    firstname = "firstname",
    lastname = "lastname",
    nickname = "nickname",
    locale = "locale",
    birthDate = "birthdate",
    currency = "USD",
    ipAddress = "127.0.0.1",
    address = address,
    mobilePhone = "+1 123 456 7890"
)
```

However I get a warning about the indentation:

```
warning FS0058: Possible incorrect indentation: this token is offside of context started at position (30:19). Try indenting this token further or using standard formatting conventions.
```

Obviously if I do not use *named parameters* or put everything in a single line, the warning disappears. But I want to format this in a way that is legible.

**Is there a way to format a method call on multiple lines in F# without having a warning?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just have to indent the params past the location of initial assignment. This line - > 
let request = Models.UserService.CreateUserRequest(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formal description of Lightweight Syntax is contained in the [F# language spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/), and the particular feature you are after is called Offside Context. This will allow you to reduce indentation to the column of the last context plus one or more additional columns. The Offside Context will be encountered immediately after the `=` assignment in a `Let` context, as well as after the opening paren in a `Paren` context.

In effect, you can have an indentation like this:

```
let request =
    Models.UserService.CreateUserRequest(
        email = "email@example.com",
        password = "password",
        ... )
```

Comment: Note that as of F# 4.5, backet-like chars within trailing `)` can also be de-intented one level back if it is not ambiguous with the containing scope: https://gist.github.com/cartermp/05a92000a7a2277dd8c9a78501614788#file-fs45-undentation-fsx